# Java - Better way to split a string into just one array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I only want the first element from `s.split(",")` and I need to return value to be in a String array.

How can I make this code a one liner?

```
String [] sd = s.split(",");
String [] sf = new String[]{sd[0]};
```

I tried `s.split(",",1);` but it just adds it all to the first element without actually splitting it.

Comment: So you want a String array where the first element is the substring of `s` from 0 to the index of the first occurrence of `,` right? Why not `String sd[] = {s.split(",")}`

Comment: Because only the first element is desired.  Yes it is easy to get the first element from that but the OP wants it in one line :)

Comment: Just append the second line to the first line without a newline inbetween and you've got your one-liner!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

```
String [] sf = {sd.substring(0,sd.indexOf(','))};
```

If you only need the first token of the comma separated String, using `substring` and `indexOf` would be more efficient than `split`.

Of course this code will throw an exception if the input String doesn't contain a `','`.

Answer (score 9):

```
String [] sf = new String[]{s.split(",")[0]};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Apache Commons Lang, you can simply use [`substringBefore`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringBefore(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

```
String[] sf = { StringUtils.substringBefore(s, ",") };
```